# Get the amount of likes/dislikes for a YouTube video via API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How do I get the amount of likes/dislikes for a YouTube video via **YouTube API**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can query the YouTube API like this:

```
<?php

$curlhandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=computers&max-results=10&orderby=viewCount");
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
curl_close($curlhandle);

$json = json_decode($response);


foreach ($json->data->items as $result)
{

        echo '<div class="video"><a href="'.$result->player->default.'" target="_blank">';
        echo '<img src="'.$result->thumbnail->hqDefault.'">';
        echo ' <div class="title"> '.$result->title.'</div><div class="rating">'.$result->likeCount.'</div></a></div>';
        //print_r($result);

}
```

?>

Comment: The key part here is adding `v=2` to the query parameters. Likes and dislikes don't show up in the first version of the API.

Comment: This is old.  is it still good or do you have to use an API KEY now

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java API, then you could get the likes dislikes as follows:

```
YtRaing ytRating = videoEntry.getYtRating();
int likes = ytRating.getNumLikes();
int dislikes = ytRating.getNumDislikes();
```

videoEntry, is the VideoEntry variable from (com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry)

Answer (score 3):

If you are wondering where the dislikes are, dislikeCount = ratingCount - likeCount

Answer (score 2):

Likes count, Dislikes can be fetched by setting **part** as **statistics**

Below is the python code:

```
payload = {'id': search_result["id"]["videoId"], 'part': 'statistics', 'key': DEVELOPER_KEY}
l = requests.Session().get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', params=payload)    
print l.text
```

Response will be:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/0NR0uhQMzlaae_et8wHFZKsdFPA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/vBL_50n3XI1eQcsdivfxN_g9c2M\"",
   "id": "hMncTg0iBko",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "10281",
    "likeCount": "61",
    "dislikeCount": "9",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "1"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```