# How to add the new Yotube's Vote up & Vote down counts feature in my application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, youtube, youtube-api, voting-system

Hi 
I am creating an app in which I am integrating Youtube.
I want to show the vote up & vote down counts for the selected you tube video instead of the ratings as it is shown in the You Tube App for iPad.
I referred to the following link:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_displaying_video_information.html

But this link is not having information related to the votes.

Please someone suggest how to implement this.It will be a great help.

iPhoneDev

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the API on iOS, but the Zend Gdata has this method: `$videoEntry->getVideoRatingInfo()`.

This is the array it returns:

```
array (
  'average' => '4.4293017',
  'numRaters' => '2348',
)
```

Seems like no accurate like/dislike-counts are retrieved.

**Edit:**
I looked more into it and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961343/239527). Hopefully it helps.