# API Youtube, how to get like and dislikes

Tags: php, api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

On a website, i use API Youtube with ZendGdata for retrieve all video of a user and create webpage with the video and his informations.

Now i need to add a system for like or dislikes video on my website, and i need to retrieve the number of likes and dislikes.

(Yes, there are 2 questions here^^)

So, i retrieve for example title with `$videoEntry->getVideoTitle();`, number of views with `$videoEntry->getVideoViewCount();` but how i can retrieve number of likes/dislikes ?

And how i can vote for a video on my website ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619313/get-the-amount-of-likes-dislikes-for-a-youtube-video-via-api

Comment: Already test, doesn't work...

Answer (score 11):

If you take a look at the `videos` resource in YouTube 3.0 API, among the values included are:

- `likeCount`
- `dislikeCount`

Full details here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

If you're using the YouTube 2.0 API, then check out the `<yt:rating>` tag, which contains the following fields:

- `numLikes`
- `numDislikes`

More info here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:rating

Comment: I have an object $videoEntry with $yt->getUserUploads($username);. With this, i have nothing like "rating" "numLikes" or something like this...

Comment: Do you have a link to the full list of methods e.g., getVideoTitle(), that $videoEntry exposes? It's hard to help without seeing that.

Answer (score 7):

An update to Cormac answer is that youtube will remove this and you can use it for yourself only.

```
Note: The statistics.dislikeCount property will be made private as of December 13, 2021. This means that the property will only be included in an API response if the API request was authenticated by the video owner. See the revision history for more information.
```

Comment: This is weird because some tools using the API still can request dislikeCount of any video in YouTube even if the request was not authenticated by the video owner. For example **livecounts.io** https://livecounts.io/youtube-live-view-counter/Vt-Wf7d0CFo I wonder what's here different?

Comment: @Thielicious old counts from database maybe, it do not show dislike for new videos

Comment: @Thielicious livecounts.io seems to be using APIs from https://www.returnyoutubedislike.com/

Comment: @Meera Yeah I already know, forgot to tell here.