# How can I get the count of likes and dislikes of any video on Youtube?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to create a database of YouTube videos with counts of likes and dislikes clustered on the basis of genres. So I need a data-set of **each and every** video on YouTube. So far the data API supports queries fired only for a single URL. Further I am not sure if Data API supports going through each and every video which seems unfeasible. Is there any way I can get the task done. Should I try to crawl, even tough I am not sure if that is legal?

Also I am using a web based architecture for it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This post does it in PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619313/get-the-amount-of-likes-dislikes-for-a-youtube-video-via-api

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 that is only for a single video.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube imposes a soft limit of about 500. There is no current way to get more than that through the API.

Full details: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4282

Relevant Excerpt:

"We can't provide more than ~500 search results for any arbitrary YouTube query via the API without the quality of the search results severely degrading (duplicates, etc.).

The v1/v2 GData API was updated back in November to limit the number of search results returned to 500. If you specify a start-index of 500 or more, you won't get back any results.

This was supposed to have also gone into effect for the v3 API (which uses a different method of paging through results) but it apparently was not pushed out, so it is still possible to retrieve up to 1000 search results in v3—the last 500 of which are usually of bad quality.

The change to limit v3 to 500 search results will be pushed out sometime in the near future. There will no longer be nextPageTokens returned once you hit 500 results.

I understand that the totalResults that are returned is much higher than 500 in all of these cases, but that is not the same thing as saying that we can effectively return all X million possible results. It's meant as an estimate of the total size of the set of videos that match a query and normally isn't very useful."